# O que está acontecendo aqui neste programa em C?

Tags: c

Eu estou fazendo um programa em que o usuário entra com 10 valores, e no final disto, apresenta uma mensagem dizendo o total do valor.

**Meu código :**

```
int rep,valor,soma;

    while(rep < 10) {

    printf("Digite um valor : ");
    scanf("%d",&valor);

    soma += valor;

    rep = rep + 1;  

    }

    printf("Total dos valores : %d ", soma);
```

O que eu não consegui entender é por que ele adiciona mais um ao total da soma, por exemplo se o input dos 10 valores for 100, ele adiciona como 101.

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Quando eu coloco no código `soma = 0`, ele vai normal, mas caso eu não faça, ocorre isto.

O que está acontecendo então ?

Comment: Possivelmente é uma questão do compilador inicializar suas variáveis. Como você não definiu o valor que elas iniciam, pode ser que a variável iniciou com valor 1. Eu testei no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/Iul5/0) e resultou em 100, mas no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/4BpqWb) resultou em 150505460. Ou seja, se você não inicializar a variável, o comportamento não pode ser previsto.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta também, e por ter testado, você também me mostrou que eu preciso sempre inicializar variáveis locais.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sempre que você cria uma variável local a uma função, ela é alocada numa área de memória chamada "a pilha". Ela contém as variáveis locais e mais algumas informações que permitem que o computador saiba, quando uma função termina de ser executada, pra que ponto da função anterior ela tem que voltar, e assim sucessivamente, até chegar à `main()`.

Uma característica dessa pilha é que, se uma função é invocada, ela utiliza parte dessa memória para guardar suas funções locais. Depois que essa função retorna, a memória que ela utilizava é liberada, e se depois o código que chamara essa função chama uma outra, ela usa **o mesmo espaço de memória que a primeira função usou** para armazenar as variáveis locais da segunda. Além do mais, ela não se preocupa em zerar essa região de memória nem depois de alocar o espaço, nem antes de liberá-lo de novo.

O resultado disso tudo é que o valor que você encontrar numa variável local não inicializada vai depender de quais funções rodaram anteriormente naquele programa e como elas terminaram a execução delas. Em outras palavras, e tomando emprestada a terminologia do padrão C, quando você lê o valor de uma variável local não inicializada, o comportamento é *indefinido*. Isto é, qualquer valor pode estar lá. No seu caso, calhou de ser um; poderia ser -1.357.928, também.

Qual a lição aprendida? **Sempre inicialize as suas variáveis locais ao declará-las**. Vai economizar aborrecimentos mais cedo ou mais tarde.

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado pela resposta, aprendi muito já com ela, verdade isto, aprendi uma lição, sempre inicializar as variáveis locais ao declará-las, vou levar esta lição comigo. Não sabia que ele podia ser um valor indefinido, pensava que seria sempre 1, e de novo, muito obrigado pelas informações.